# How can I display a multiplication table without using nested loops?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1,11,1):
  for j in range(1,11,1):
    print(i*j, end="\t")
  print()
```

**Output**

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Is it possible to display this multiplication table without using nested loops?

If Yes, how?

I mean, I want to use only one loop.

Comment: No, not really.  You can build up the output strings with comprehensions, but those are essentially loops.

Comment: Yeah, does a list comprehension count as a nested loop?

Comment: @merlin2011, can u show me an example?

Comment: I am curious why the necessity to avoid nesting loops?

Comment: @NateB, Linear time?

Comment: @user366312 It doesn't change the complexity. No matter how many loops you do, it performs 100 pieces of work.

Comment: You can print the entire thing as a single string literal, with no loops at all.

Comment: @user366312 it will be `O(N)` where `N=n^2` as @Barmar stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop 100 times, and then use division and modulus to determine your current row and column, and then calculate the appropriate product.

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    row = 1 + i // 10
    col = 1 + i % 10
    print(row * col, end="\t")
    if col == 10:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for some other function to do the nested loop for you, you could use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for a, b in product(range(1, 11), repeat=2):
...     print(a * b, end="\t")
...     if b == 10:
...         print()
...
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without *any* explicit loops, or even the keyword `for`.

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> from functools import partial
>>> 
>>> print("\n".join(map(lambda n: "".join(map("{:<3}".format, map(partial(mul, n), range(1,11)))), range(1,11))))
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 
2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16 18 20 
3  6  9  12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
4  8  12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 
5  10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 
6  12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 
7  14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 
8  16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 
9  18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

It's still O(n^2), though. No matter how you write this, you need to compute and output O(n^2) products.

The *simplest* solution, though, is with two loops like you already have.